# VB.Net Parse JSON Array into Dictionary for Key:Value pairs to achieve same result as Xojo Code, (example)

Tags: json, vb.net, dictionary, xojo

I need to duplicate what I can do in Xojo in VB.Net. THis will be for custom Code on Kodak Rules Based Automation that uses embedded VB.Net. How do I make VB.net code do the same thing that the Xojo code I show below does. As much as I have searched for solutions, nothing I try in VB does anything but give me errors trying to use a dictionary to retrieve the values. I've installed the Newtonsoft DLL in Prinergy so the various methods for "deserializing" the JSON I've found don't give me compile errors but getting beyond that to duplicate what I can do in Xojo is escaping me.

I need to Parse a JSON response from a REST API to determune if a Name has a specific status. I have searched for examples here and have tried numerous attempts to adapt what I have found for VB.Net, but I cannot get any code past the following to work:

```
Dim jsonstring As String = responseFromServer
Dim Worksteps As Dictionary(Of String, String) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(jsonstring)
```

Here is a sample of the JSON that is returned from the VB.Net code that is working:

```
{
  "error": null,
  "worksteps": [
    {
      "id": "_210504_125916572_029875",
      "name": "Sheet_1  4/4",
      "job": {
        "id": "060671-21",
        "name": "2021 Laramie High School"
      },
      "status": "COMPLETED",
      "amountPlanned": 544,
      "wastePlanned": 60,
      "amountProduced": 169,
      "wasteProduced": 69,
      "deviceId": "114",
      "types": [
        "ConventionalPrinting"
      ],
      "sequenceType": "SheetfedPrinting",
      "start": "2021-05-05T09:46:06-05:00",
      "end": "2021-05-05T09:48:38-05:00",
      "startPlanned": "2021-05-05T07:52:22-05:00",
      "endPlanned": null,
      "setuptimePlanned": 0,
      "prodtimePlanned": 0,
      "actualTimes": [
        {
          "timeTypeGroupName": "Production time",
          "timeTypeName": "Execution time",
          "duration": 33
        },
        {
          "timeTypeGroupName": "Production time",
          "timeTypeName": "Setup time",
          "duration": 79
        },
        {
          "timeTypeGroupName": "Auxiliary time",
          "timeTypeName": "Auxiliary time",
          "duration": 40
        },
        {
          "timeTypeGroupName": "",
          "timeTypeName": "",
          "duration": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "_210506_072306983_020035",
      "name": "Sheet_2  4/4",
      "job": {
        "id": "060671-21",
        "name": "2021 Laramie High School"
      },
      "status": "WAITING",
      "amountPlanned": 0,
      "wastePlanned": 0,
      "amountProduced": 0,
      "wasteProduced": 0,
      "deviceId": "XL106_Pool",
      "types": [
        "ConventionalPrinting"
      ],
      "sequenceType": "SheetfedPrinting",
      "start": null,
      "end": null,
      "startPlanned": null,
      "endPlanned": null,
      "setuptimePlanned": 0,
      "prodtimePlanned": 0,
      "actualTimes": null
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is working Xojo 2021r1.1 Code that does what I am attempting to accomplish in VB.Net:

```
Public Function ParseWorkstepsJSON(jsontext As String, sheetname As String) As Boolean
  ' Parse the JSON and Put the resulting Worksteps Array into a new Dictionary
  Var jsonDict As Dictionary = ParseJSON(jsontext)
  Var JobWorksteps() As Object = jsonDict.Lookup("worksteps", New Dictionary())
  
  ' Loop through each Action Dictionary in the Actions Dictionary and Process the data within into an Array of values
  Worksteps.ResizeTo(JobWorksteps.LastIndex,1)
  For idx As Integer = 0 to JobWorksteps.LastIndex
    Var wkstp As Dictionary = Dictionary(JobWorksteps(idx))
    ' Process the data in the Action in the order we want to store it in the array
    
    ' WorkStep Name
    If Not (wkstp.Value("name") = Nil) Then
      Worksteps(idx,0) = wkstp.Value("name")
    Else
      Worksteps(idx,0) = ""
    End If
    
    ' WorkStep Status
    If Not (wkstp.Value("status") = Nil) Then
      Worksteps(idx,1) = wkstp.Value("status")
    Else
      Worksteps(idx,1) = ""
    End If
  Next
  
  ' Determine whether "Sheet_1" staus = "COMPLETED"
  Var b As Boolean
  Var s As String
  For idx As Integer = 0 To Worksteps.LastIndex
    s = Worksteps(idx,0).NthField(" ",1)
    If s = sheetname Then
      If Worksteps(idx,1) = "COMPLETED" Then
        Return True
      End If
    End If
  Next
  Return False 
End Function
```

I do not have to put the JSON into a Dictionary in VB.Net like in Xojo, which was what I was attempting, if there is a different way to accomplish the task of determining whether a specific "name" value in the JSON has a corresponding "status" with a Value of "COMPLETED"

Comment: I read your goals / requirements and about the work you have done so far. I see the JSON text and VB.NET code. I missed the question. What is your question?

Comment: The question is how to make VB.net code do the same thing that the Xojo code does. As much as I have searched for solutions, nothing I try in VB does anything but give me errors trying to use the dictionary to retrieve the values.  I've installed the Newtonsoft DLL in Prinergy so the various methods for "deserializing" the JSON I've found don't give me compile errors but getting beyond that to duplicate what I can do in Xojo is escaping me.

Comment: Consider editing your post to add your question. Some skip the comments. That may help to get answers.

Answer (score 0):

For loading the JSON, it seems like something along these lines might work:

```
Dim read = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json)
```

This returns a [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), which looks to have methods equivalent to what Xojo has, allowing you to loop through the contents and check values.